# Username text input not being displayed

Tags: html, css

[image]

I've created this login page for this project I'm doing. I don't know what I've changed but the username text input is hidden. What's causing this and how do I change it so its displayed?

Answer (score 1):

Your input type is wrong. You have change to text.

`<input type="text" name="Username" ...>`

Answer (score 1):

The type needs to be changed to text for it to be visible.  Anything of type password will show the dots instead of the actual value to maintain some level of privacy.

Example:

```html
<input type="password" name="Username" placeholder="Enter Username" value="Test">
<input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Enter Username" value="Test">
```

Input types:

Text: " The default value. A single-line text field. Line-breaks are automatically removed from the input value. "

Password: "A single-line text field whose value is obscured. Will alert user if site is not secure. "

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input